# Color in status bar with React Native and react-navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` in React Native and I have changed the header color with

```
const MyScreenNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ...
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white'
  }
});
```

It does change the background color of both header and status bar, but the font color is still black in the status bar.

How can I customise the font color of the status bar?

Answer (score 1):

I use `StatusBar`

```
const RootNavigator = StackNavigator({
...
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: <Header />
  }
});
```

`header.js`

```
import { StatusBar } from 'react-native';
export default class Header extends Component<{}> {
  <View>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="#fff" />
    ...
  </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The API and documentation still changes quite frequently, but in order to style **StackNavigator**'s header, use `headerTitleStyle: { color: 'white' }`. (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#headerTitleStyle)

Comment: Hi. I am colouring the title with `headerTintColor: 'white'` but the status bar (above the title) is not affected neither with `headerTintColor` nor `headerTitleStyle`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't change status bar background color with navigationOptions by now. You should use StatusBar in your component:

```
<StatusBar
    barStyle="light-content"
    backgroundColor='blue'
/>
```